# Is the spectrum for a free quantum field theory continuous at the ground state?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I hope someone could help to confirm whether I am right on this:

The ground state of a free field theory would be a state with no particles. And the first excited state would be a one-particle state with zero momentum. Then the energy gap should be the mass of the particle. Hence,  if the particle is massive, the spectrum would be discrete there around the vacuum state; if the particle is massless,the spectrum would be continuous?

Comment: Yes, the spectrum is continuous for massless excitations (except for a case of a cavity system with non-zero ground state frequency).

Comment: You are correct! The fun part is when you have a massless field theory whose interactions produce a “mass-gap” (the energy difference between the ground state and the first excited state(s)), like in pure Yang-Mills.

Comment: What will happen to the spectrum if the massless field is evolved under some interaction adiabatically?@Vladimir Kalitvianski

Comment: Thank you, Bob! Could you detail more on this or point to some references? I am always wondering about how can one find the eigenstate of an interacting theory. @BobKnighton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $m>0$, the only point in the point spectrum is $0$ corresponding to the vacuum state. The other points are separated from it and stay  in $[m,+\infty)$. They  are parts of the continuous spectrum however.

I am referring to the Hamiltonian operator of the field associated with an inertial reference frame. The fact that the spectrum is continuous, barring the point due to the vacuum, is due to the kinetical energy of the particles which continuously varies.

I  the massless case the spectrum is continuous in $(0,+\infty)$ and $0$ is the only point of the point-spectrum part. There is no gap here obviously.

Comment: Yes, in the massive case. But OPs question essentially boils down to whether a mass gap exists in a massless free field theory, the answer to which is no.

Comment: Ok, there is an informal use of mathematical terms...Thx

Comment: I added further details correspondingly.